# React Native: Saving image URI via AsyncStorage and reloading in different React Navigation screen

Tags: image, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage, react-native-camera

I am currently trying to combine a React Native Camera [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269191/6546760) with the React Navigation v2 and want to take a picture in the first view (called CameraView), save said picture to AsyncStorage, navigate to a second view (called GalleryView) and render this picture from AsyncStorage into an image tag.

I am using RN 0.57.1, RN-Camera 1.3.1, React Navigation 2.18.0 on a Windows 10 computer emulating an Android phone running Android version 8.0.0.

This is the code for the two views:

**CameraView.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from "react-native";
import { RNCamera as Camera } from "react-native-camera";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width
  },
  capture: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: "#FFF",
    marginBottom: 15
  }
});

class CameraView extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: null
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageUri: null
    };
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    try {
      const imageData = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
        fixOrientation: true
      });
      this.setState({
        imageUri: imageData.uri
      });
      this._saveImageAsync();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err: ", err);
    }
  };

  _saveImageAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("imageUri", this.state.imageUri);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("GalleryView");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Camera
        ref={cam => {
          this.camera = cam;
        }}
        style={styles.preview}
        flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
        permissionDialogTitle={"Permission to use camera"}
        permissionDialogMessage={
          "We need your permission to use your camera phone"
        }
      >
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.capture}
          onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
          underlayColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        >
          <View />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Camera>
    );
  }
}

export default CameraView;
```

**GalleryView.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width
  },
  cancel: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 20,
    top: 20,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    color: "#FFF",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 17
  }
});

class GalleryView extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "Seismic"
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    AsyncStorage.getItem("imageUri").then(response => {
      this.setState({
        imageUri: response
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: this.state.imageUri }} style={styles.preview} />

        <Text
          style={styles.cancel}
          onPress={() => this.state.setState({ imageData: null })}
        >
          X
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="Map View"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GalleryView;
```

The first-mentioned example works fine, but when trying to use the AsyncStorage I get the error below after snapping the image and executing *navigate()* to the second view.

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.state.imageUri')
>
> This error is located at:
>       in GalleryView (at SceneView.js:9)
>       in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:478)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:58)
>       in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
>       in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
>       in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
>       in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
>       in StackView (at createNavigator.js:57)
>       in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
>       in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
>       in NavigationContainer (at routes.js:39)
>       in Routes (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:44)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>   >
>
> > This error is located at:
> >         in NavigationContainer (at routes.js:39)
> >         in Routes (at renderApplication.js:34)
> >         in RCTView (at View.js:44)
> >         in RCTView (at View.js:44)
> >         in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33) render
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\src\screens\GalleryView.js:25:11
> >     proxiedMethod
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:44:35
> >     finishClassComponent
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10563:21
> >     updateClassComponent
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10505:4
> >     beginWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11338:8
> >     performUnitOfWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14091:21
> >     workLoop
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14129:41
> >     renderRoot
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14226:15
> >     performWorkOnRoot
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15193:17
> >     performWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15090:24
> >     performSyncWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15047:14
> >     requestWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14925:19
> >     scheduleWork
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14711:16
> >     enqueueSetState
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7700:17
> >     setState
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:372:31
> >     dispatch
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-navigation\src\createNavigationContainer.js:342:22
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-navigation\src\getChildNavigation.js:56:33
> >     _callee2$
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\src\screens\CameraView.js:88:16
> >     tryCatch
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:44
> >     invoke
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:30
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:28
> >     tryCatch
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:44
> >     invoke
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:152:28
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:162:19
> >     tryCallOne
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:295:23
> >     _callTimer
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:152:14
> >     _callImmediatesPass
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:200:17
> >     callImmediates
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:464:30
> >     __callImmediates
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:320:6
> >     
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
> >     __guard
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297:10
> >     flushedQueue
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:17
> >     invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
> >         C:\Users\msteinbrink\Safeguard\seismic-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:130:11

I would appreciate if someone could point out how to properly use AsyncStorage with React Navigation to render a previously saved image from React Native Camera. As you probably could tell, I am fairly new to React Native, so please tell me if I got the concept completely wrong or anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```AsyncStorage``` is asynchronous. Add a ```isLoaded``` flag to your state. Set to true when the Async portion is done. Render a loading screen until that flag is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wainages comment, I made it work. I added the state isLoaded in GalleryView and show just the text "Loading" before the async operation is done.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  Image,
  View
} from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width
  },
  cancel: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 20,
    top: 20,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    color: "#FFF",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 17
  }
});

class GalleryView extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "Seismic"
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageUri: null,
      isLoaded: false
    };

    AsyncStorage.getItem("imageUri").then(response => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        imageUri: response
      });
    });
  }

  renderImage() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: this.state.imageUri }} style={styles.preview} />
        <Text
          style={styles.cancel}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ path: null })}
        >
          X
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderLoadingScreen() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.cancel}>Loading</Text>
        <Button
          title="Map View"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.isLoaded ? this.renderImage() : this.renderLoadingScreen()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GalleryView;
```