# How to connect to camera

Tags: react-native

How can I connect to phone camera with react native.  I want to access the phone's camera and connect to the phone's camera at any time and watch what's happening with the camera.  Kind of like a mini stalker.  Is it possible to do this with react native?

Haven't tried anything yet.  I can't figure out how to implement it.  Is there an article somewhere about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the camera - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269099/how-to-access-the-camera-react-native)

Comment: you can also use react-native-image-crop-picker.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker it also working

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269099/how-to-access-the-camera-react-native/74888199#74888199 this is about vision-camera - new default camera component for RN