# React native RN Camera crachs onTextRecognized

Tags: android, react-native, camera, android-camera

I am trying to get(read) text in image. Fot this I am using **"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",**

Whenever I open camera it works fine. But when I add this line into code App craches without any log

```
 onTextRecognized={({textBlocks})=>{console.log("textBlocks===", textBlocks)}}
```

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269099/how-to-access-the-camera-react-native/74888199#74888199 it is about vision-camera because `react-native-camera` is deprecated

Comment: I want to read text from image. is it possible ?

Comment: if you need text recognition from an image not from a camera better to use https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/tree/main/text-recognition based on ML Kit from google.